# How can I link an entire section of a Bootstrap Progress Bar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want a user to be able to click through a section of a Bootstrap Progress Bar (multiple bars) to another page. Is this possible? If so, how?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/#multiple-bars

UPDATE: If I enter this in jsfiddle, the progress bars completely disappear:

```
<!-- 
Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<div class="container"> 

<! # NOT WORKING (with href) # !/> 
<div class="progress">
<a href="#">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 15%" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</a>
<a href="#">
<div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</a>
<a href="#">
<div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</a>
</div>
```

However, this works just fine without the href & a tag:

```
<!-- 
Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<div class="container"> 
<! # WORKING (no href) # !/>
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 15%" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
<div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
<div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, just add an `<a>` tag around each of the `<div>` elements?

Comment: What that's it?! Awesome! Thanks I'll try that out. Didn't think it would be so simple with the resizing but that makes sense.

Comment: @ScottSkiles use <a> tag will not cover entire bar section. However, if you use jquery, you can use ```$(".bg-info").click(()=>{
  window.open("http://www.google.com"); 
})```to set event to open a new link so the event will cover entire section. (you can try it use dev tools of chrome.)

Comment: @ObsidianAge - I did not get this to work :-(  Thank you caoglish but I'd prefer an HTML solution that I can use Django templates with (e.g., href="{% url 'something' %}")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked perfectly!

```
<!-- 
    Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<div class="container"> 

    <div class="progress">

    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 15%" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks, Obsidian.